# Im trying to find a 216 point font

Tags: color, export, path

I am trying to make Banners for our "Red Granite Labor Day Celebration" It is a volunteer run festival. I cannot find a 216 point font to download. Arial, Times New Roman, any font will do. Any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Fonts don't come in point sizes. You set the point size in the software you are using.

Comment: Do know that, in most software using fonts, you are not limited to the values as they are given in the dropdown menu. You can click in the line to edit the point value as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Arial or Times New Roman should be fine. In fact, pretty much any font should work with this purpose. I just started a blank page in MS Word, typed a few characters in Arial and changed the font size to 216, so really don't see what the problem is on your end.